# Faster string replacement in python

Tags: python, string, string-matching

Consider the following string replacement python codes:

```
import re

s = 'head abc.sys!0x1234 middle defg.sys!0x1a2b tail' # this could be potentially very long

d = {'0x1234' : 'Iamshorter',
     '0x1a2b' : 'Iammuchlonger' }

pat = re.compile(r'(\w+.\w+)!(0x[\d\w]+)')

while True:
    m = pat.search(s)
    if not m:
        break
    module, addr = m.groups()
    start, end = m.span()
    s = s[:start] + '%s!%s' % (module, d[addr]) + s[end:]

print s
```

It will output

```
head abc.sys!Iamshorter middle defg.sys!Iammuchlonger tail
```

I am looking for faster python idiom such that the power of python's regular expression can be unleashed. I tried to use re.sub(), but I had hard time to make 'repl' as a function of matched string. Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You already compiled your expression. You probably won't get much more juice out of the search algorithm. You might need to seek your high performance in lower level languages like C to write an even "rawer" and faster matching pattern.

Comment: The main question is why you are looking for a faster solution. Preemptive optimization are in many instances over-rated, and makes your code overly complicated.

Comment: @eandersson: I posted this as a solicit for anything that I might not know, such as the way we use built-in modules in a correct way, so that I can learn from the expert. This code does not have to be optimized since it's just my script doing the substring replacement. I am eager to learn from the python experts; I am not sure why someone gave me a downvote. :(

Comment: I benchmarked for shi*s and giggles.  Using `bytearray` to do in place replacement - 1ms faster on average.  Using `findall` and `replace` or `re.sub`, about 1ms faster.  Not going to do much better I don't think.  See @eandersson's comment.

Answer (score 0):

The only suggestion I have would be to use the optional 'pos' parameter of the [search function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) so that you're not checking through the part of the string that you've already checked.